# Java reactor - chain Mono<Void> with another async task producing Mono<Object>

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I have the below async tasks:

```java
public class AsyncValidationTask {
    // Returns Mono.error(new Exception()) if error, otherwise Mono.empty()
    public Mono<Void> execute(Object o);
}
```

```java
public class AsyncSaveTask {
    // Returns Mono.error(new Exception()) if error, otherwise Mono of Object
    public Mono<Object> execute(Object o);
}
```

And below Service class:

```java
public class AsyncService {

    private AsyncValidationTask validation;

    private AsyncSaveTask save;

    public Mono<Object> validateAndSave(Object o) {
        return Mono.defer(() -> this.validation.execute(o))
                   // Right now, the problem is that when validation completes successfully, it 
                   // emits Mono.empty hence the flatMap chained below will not be invoked at all.
                   .flatMap(dontcare -> this.save.execute(o))
    }
}
```

As shown above, I tried to use `flatMap` to chain the `AsyncSaveTask.execute` call if the `AsyncValidationTask.execute` completes successfully, it won't work because nothing is emitted (Mono.empty) upon completion.

I also consider `then` to chain the second call, but it will always invoke the chained call regardless of the Mono.error produced by the first validation call.

How can I chain them properly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## `.then` for terminal only sources to chain

Use `.then`, in order to **chain** your execution with the process, which only sends a terminal signal.

Also, pay attention, if you need to do something on the error signal, then you have to accompany your `.then` with `onErrorResume` beforehand.

```
public class AsyncService {

    private AsyncValidationTask validation;

    private AsyncSaveTask save;

    public Mono<Object> validateAndSave(Object o) {
        return Mono.defer(() -> this.validation.execute(o))
                   .onErrorResume(t -> ...) // should be before then
                   .then(this.save.execute(o))
    }
}
```

## `.defer` in order to postpone mono creation

In order to execute the `this.save.execute(o)` only in case of successful validation, you have to wrap it in `Mono.defer` as well:

```
public class AsyncService {

    private AsyncValidationTask validation;

    private AsyncSaveTask save;

    public Mono<Object> validateAndSave(Object o) {
        return Mono.defer(() -> this.validation.execute(o))
                   .onErrorResume(t -> ...) // should be before then
                   .then(Mono.defer(() -> this.save.execute(o)))
    }
}
```

***Usually, it is not necessary***, because `Mono` is a ***LAZY*** type which **SHOULD** *start* doing work only in case ***subscription*** happened (subscription == `.subscribe()`).

The implementation of `Mono#then` **guarantees** that subscription to `Mono` returned by the `this.save.execute` the method starts ***RIGHT AFTER*** the `Mono.defer(() -> this.validation.execute(o))` **completed**.

The only reason why execution may start earlier may be a *PURPOSE* (e.g., business logic which provides such behavior on purpose - caching; hot source, etc.) ***OR*** an *INCORRECT* implementation of the  `this.save.execute(o)` which starts doing work regardless of actual subscription.

## Design your Implementation properly

In general, it is a good practice to ensure that API which does work and expose that work as a `Publisher` (e.g. `Mono` | `Flux`) is Lazy.

It means that the API creator MUST ensure that the work execution happens only in case the user has subscribed to the given `Publisher` instance.

For example, if your async API does `CompletableFuture` creation underneath, it worth to manually wrap your `CompletableFuture` creation into `Mono.defer` or to use proper method extension, e.g `Mono.fromFuture(Supplier<? extends CompletableFuture<? extends T>> futureSupplier)`

### Executors example

Let's consider how to make a regular ThreadPool task submission Reactive.

```
interface Executor  {
  Future<T> execute(Callable<T> runnable); 
}
```

So, in order to make `Executor` reactive, we have to create something like the following:

```
interface ReactiveExecutor {
   Mono<T> execute(Callable<T> runnable);
}
```

#### Incorrect Implementation

The following is a possible implementation of such an adapter which works:

```
class ReactiveExecutorAdapter {
   final Executor delegate;

   ...


   Mono<T> execute(Callable<T> runnable) {
      MonoProcessor<T> result = MonoProcessor.create();
      Future<T> task = delegate.execute(() -> {
          T value = runnable.call();
          result.onNext(value);
          result.onComplet();
          return value;
      });

      return result.doOnCancel(() -> task.cancel());
   }
}
```

Definitely, such an implementation will be working. However, it has a few critical issues:

1. Execution starts on the method invocation (which somewhat contradicts to lazy behavior of reactive streams `Publisher`)
2. Since execution starts before the actual task subscription, we have to create a stateful `Mono`, which supports later subscription.
3. This implementation does not handle the case when there are no Subscribers at all (e.g., execution has started, but no `.subscribe` method happened (then we got value leak which impossible to handle)
4. It is too hacky in general to be a solution. Also, in order to prevent all the previously mentioned cases, it is necessary to wrap every call on `Mono execute(..)` with `Mono.defer` outside of the implementation (see the original problem in the question). Subsequently, it leads to the fact that an API user can easily 'shoot your self in the foot' forgetting to wrap execution with an extra `.defer`

#### So, how to solve it, then?

Basically, it is enough to move the  `Mono.defer` into the library internals. It will make the life of the API users much easier since they don't have to think when it is necessary to use deferring (hence - less possible issues).

For example, the simplest solution for our Reactive Executor can be the following:

```
class ReactiveExecutorAdapter {
   final Executor delegate;

   ...


   Mono<T> execute(Callable<T> runnable) {
      Mono.defer(() -> {
          MonoProcessor<T> result = MonoProcessor.create();
          Future<T> task = delegate.execute(() -> {
              T value = runnable.call();
              result.onNext(value);
              result.onComplet();
              return value;
          });

          return result.doOnCancel(() -> task.cancel());
     })
   }
}
```

By just deferring the execution, we can solve at least one problem for sure - ensure value is not leaked anymore.

#### But, How to solve it correctly?

However, in order to solve all the possible problems in that particular case, we may use `Mono.create` which is properly designed for adopting async API:

```
class ReactiveExecutorAdapter {
   final Executor delegate;

   ...


   Mono<T> execute(Callable<T> runnable) {
      Mono.crete(monoSink -> {

          Future<T> task = delegate.execute(() -> {
              T value = runnable.call();
              monoSink.complete(value);
          });

          monoSink.doOnCancel(task::cancel);
     })
   }
}
```

using `Mono.create` we have a guarantee of lazy execution on every subscriber. 
Also, using `MonoSink` API, we can quickly hook on all the essential signals from the subscriber.
Finally, Mono.create ensures that in case of anything, the value will be discarded appropriately.

Finally, having such an API it is not necessary to use defer for all the cases

Comment: Can I just do `onErrorStop` instead of `onErrorResume` and chain the second call without `Mono.defer`?

Comment: It does not work like that. `onErrorStop` is a way to stop `onErrorContinue` operator. It is a specification violation if a terminal signal is swallowed in the middle of the chain.

just added a couple of notes on how to design API which exposes reactive streams

Comment: I will accept this as the answer and use this as reference when I read more reactor documents. Thanks!

Comment: Added an example of proper implementation on top of async task

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly, but.. Looking at the signatures of methods in OP's question, they don't really look like "async tasks" for an `ExecutorService`, they look like mere `Mono`-producing methods, something that routinely comes across in 'reactive' world. then the question is just in combining them with something like

```
Mono<Object> validateAndSave(Object o) {
    return validation.execute(o)
               .then(save.execute(o));
```

`.then` will ignore elements emitted by the source (i.e.`validation.execute`), but will not ignore error signal. so in case of `onError` your method will return `Mono.error()`, otherwise it will return what `save.execute` returned.